# How to track new files with VS2019 Git

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with the new Git menu interface.
My project is all in an OnPremise TFS git repository.

When I add new files, they don't get the red checkmark.
`git status` shows them in the *Untracked* section.

I know I can to git add on each file to add them to the *Tracked* section but since everything else goes very fine within Visual Studio, I was wondering what is the right way to do this without relying on the CLI.

I thought of 2 ways:

1. have a preference to get all new files tracked by default
2. have a contextual menu to start to add the new file to the tracked section (like TFVC had)

I searched in the *Preferences* window, in the *Solution explorer* pane and also in the *Git Modifications* pane but wasn'T able to find it anywhere.

Is `git add` the only actual option?

Comment: You can stage the files in the git changes window, which is the same as `git add`. That doesn’t track them though, you need to commit them.

Comment: You're right. As soon as I clicked the + icon of the Changes sections to send them to the Staged Changes section, the CLI was not complaining about any untracked change anymore. Only unfortunate that the red check does not also appear. An option like TFVC to right-clik/Add to Source Code Management would have made it more streamlined I think. And the option to always stage new files would be event better for my workflos ;) Thank you for your input!